# Rails. Different application layouts for different parts of the site.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I'm building a web site with a part that users can browse and administrative panel. How can use different application layouts for different parts of the site? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes , you can use different layouts for different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout method to render different layout for different controllers.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :admin_layout

private

  def admin_layout
    # Check if logged in, because current_user could be nil.
    if logged_in? and current_user.is_able_to('siteadmin')
      "admin"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use seperate views, for example if your run `rails g controller home index` you get a `home_controller.rb` and in the `views` folder you get a home folder with an  `index` view. In your controller you can put your logic there and present it in the view.

Check this [link](http://www.ulearnr.com/freetut/index) seems to be good for beginners